# Error when stacking SSH command arguments within a bash script using other scripts as variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have a csv file called addresses.csv which looks like this,

```
node-1,xx.xxx.xx.xx,us-central-a
....
node-9,xxx.xx.xxx.xx,us-east1-a
```

I have a script below called 0run.sh,

```
#!/bin/bash
username='user'
persist="bash /home/${username}/Documents/scripts/disk/persistentDisk.sh"
first="bash /home/${username}/Documents/scripts/disk/firstAttach.sh"

while IFS=, read -r int ip <&3; do
  if [ "$int" == "node-1" ]; then
--->ssh -i ~/.ssh/key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ${username} ${ip} "${persist}; ${first}"<---
  else
    ssh -i ~/.ssh/key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ${username} ${ip} "${first}"
  fi
done 3<addresses.csv
```

The error occurs in the part of the code where I drew the arrows.

When it runs on `node-1`, instead of running `..persistentDisk.sh` followed by `..firstAttach.sh`, it only runs `..persistentDisk.sh` and gives me the following error before it runs `..persistentDisk`.

```
bash: /home/user/Documents/scripts/disk/firstAttach.sh: No such file or directory
```

The rest of the script runs completely fine. The only error occurs at this one part where it misses the 2nd script.

When I run the command like this it runs fine.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ${username} ${ext} "${first}"
```

When I run it like this, it runs fine as well.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l user xxx.xx.xxx.xx "bash /home/${username}/Documents/scripts/disk/persistentDisk.sh; bash /home/${username}/Documents/scripts/disk/firstAttach.sh"
```

When I run the command like with a `\` before the `;` to escape it like this,

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ${username} ${ext} "${persist}\; ${first}"
```

I get the following error, and neither scripts run within the `node-1` part of the code, but the rest of the code's else loops run fine.

```
bash: /home/user/Documents/scripts/disk/persistentDisk.sh;: No such file or directory
```

Why can't I stack the 2 commands within the if statement in the ssh using variables?

Comment: My guess is that second script is being executed on your local machine due to semi-colon. Try running your script with `-x` switch to see debugging info from bash.

Comment: is there a way to escape the character or something?

Comment: Try using a backslash before `;` but ideally everything in double quotes should have been passed to ssh command in first place.

Comment: @SameerNaik i updated my question with your suggestion and the error

Comment: Can you try removing `bash` from `persist` and `first` variables? and make those files executable?

Comment: I second the recommendation of running the script with `bash -x`, or putting `set -x` in the script before the relevant section. This'll make the shell print the equivalent of the commands it's executing, so you can get a better idea what's actually happening. Note: it sometimes quotes/escapes things in unexpected ways, but it'll print something *equivalent* to what's actually being executed.

Comment: Try replace `while IFS=, read -r int ip <&3; do` by `while IFS=, read -ru 3 int ip foo; do`

Comment: what does the -ru flag do ? @F.Hauri

Comment: `-u 3` flag tell read to acced `/dev/fd/3` instead of `STDIN`

Comment: If I clearly understand: your **real** problem consist to leave *`STDIN`* free for interaction in target host! Right?

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understand: your **real** problem consist to leave *`STDIN`* free for interaction in target host!

### About `read` and redirection

Try using:

```
#!/bin/bash
username='user'
persist="bash /home/${username}/Documents/scripts/disk/persistentDisk.sh"
first="bash /home/${username}/Documents/scripts/disk/firstAttach.sh"

while IFS=, read -r -u $list int ip foo; do
  if [ "$int" == "node-1" ]; then
       echo CMD... $ip, $persist
  else
       [ "$ip" ] && echo CMD... $ip, $first
  fi
done {list}<addresses.csv
```

Tested, this èroduce:

```
CMD... xx.xxx.xx.xx, bash /home/user/Documents/scripts/disk/persistentDisk.sh
CMD... xxx.xx.xxx.xx, bash /home/user/Documents/scripts/disk/firstAttach.sh
```

- `-u` flag to read, tell to use *file descriptor* `${list}` instead of  `STDIN`
- `foo` is some useless variable used to prevent rest of line to be stored in `$ip` (`xx.xxx.xx.xx,us-central-a` in this case)
- `{list}</path/to/filename` create a new variable by finding any free *file descriptor*.

### About `ssh` (and redirection)

You could use:

```
#!/bin/bash
username='user'
persist="/home/${username}/Documents/scripts/disk/persistentDisk.sh"
first="/home/${username}/Documents/scripts/disk/firstAttach.sh"

while IFS=, read -r -u $list int ip foo; do
  [ "$int" = "node-1" ] && cmd=persist || cmd=first
  [ "$ip" ] && ssh -i ~/.ssh/key -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
                   -l ${username} ${ext} /bin/bash "${!cmd}"
  done {list}<addresses.csv
```

By using this syntax, you will keep *`STDIN`* free for script running on target host.

Comment: I get this error ```./0run.sh: line 28: syntax error near unexpected token `{list}'
./0run.sh: line 28: `done {list}<addresses.csv'```

Comment: 5.0.17(1)-release

Comment: Tested here: https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/6ir  (Note: You have to upload a test file., called `addresses.csv` :)

Comment: i keep getting that same error i dont know why i tried a bunch of things

Comment: what is the point of this part [ "$ip" ] &&

Comment: Test if `$ip` does contain something (to avoidt line containig only `---` ) This could be perfectible `ping -nc 1 $ip &>/dev/null && ssh...`